# Combo Box in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Combo box on sheet1 of a excel workbook. I add some items to it during a process.
Once I close the workbook all the items of Combo box are getting cleared. How to avoid this?

```
    Public Sub ComboBox1_Change() 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Dim match As range 
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem range("C3").Value 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Create a hidden sheet and store the values in that from the combobox before you close the workbook. When you open the workbook later, reload the combo from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add items to a range in your worksheet, somewhere hidden, and define a name for that range. In the properties of the combobox under ListFillRange, write the name that you defined for that range.

Comment: + 1 Good idea but in this case you need to mention that the user has to add the items to the named range instead of combobox at runtime `ComboBox1_Change()` else you will get a permission denied error.

Comment: Right. Plus, didn't see your comment up there. :)